# Understanding casting a struct as a void pointer

Tags: c++, c

I found this code in the rendering library for Quake 3. There is this function:

```
void R_AddDrawSurf( surfaceType_t *surface, shader_t *shader, int fogIndex, int dlightMap );`
```

It is being called in a loop somehwere else like this:

```
R_AddDrawSurf( ( void * )poly, sh, poly->fogIndex, qfalse );
```

The weird part is that poly was declared as `srfPoly_t *poly`. What is going on 
here? It is casting a `srfPoly_t` object to `(void *)` and then entering the 
function as a `surfaceType_t` object.

Here are the declaration for the relevant structs:

```
typedef enum {
  SF_BAD,
  SF_SKIP,        // ignore
  SF_FACE,
  SF_GRID,
  SF_TRIANGLES,
  SF_POLY,
  SF_MD3,
  SF_MD4,
  SF_FLARE,
  SF_ENTITY,        // beams, rails, lightning, etc that can be determined by entity
  SF_DISPLAY_LIST,

  SF_NUM_SURFACE_TYPES,
  SF_MAX = 0x7fffffff     // ensures that sizeof( surfaceType_t ) == sizeof( int )
} surfaceType_t;

typedef struct srfPoly_s {
  surfaceType_t surfaceType;
  qhandle_t   hShader;
  int       fogIndex;
  int       numVerts;
  polyVert_t    *verts;
} srfPoly_t;
```

This is working in C, but I am trying to implement something similar in C++, 
but I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'int RefDef::AddDrawSurf(surfaceType_t *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void *' to 'surfaceType_t *'
```

It would appear I cannot perform this type of cast in C++, or maybe there is
something else I am unable to understand. I am not very familiar with C++ and
would love to figure out how to set up something similar using it.

I am assuming this has something to do with type checking in C++, so it is not
allowed. How can I implement something similar in C++ in a safe way?

Comment: Basically, it's an underhanded way to do `R_AddDrawSurf(&poly->surfaceType, ...)`. For no good reason that I can see. The address of a struct is also an address of its first member, so the stars align. As to why it works in C but not C++: in C, `void*` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type, while in C++ it cannot.

Comment: It's not casting a struct to `void*`. It's casting a struct *pointer* to `void*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in C because structs are simply blocks of memory with each element in the struct laid out consecutively. This cast works because the first `n` bytes of a `srfPoly_t` struct consist of the `surfaceType_t` enum within that struct. The called function tries to interpret the passed-in `srfPoly_t` as a `surfaceType_t`, and succeeds because the first `n` bytes of the argument are, in fact, a `surfaceType_t`. Do not do this without a very good reason.

Casts from `void*`'s do not automatically occur in C++ as they do in C. You can use `reinterpret_cast` to explicitly cast between two different types of structs:

```
srfPoly_t* mySrfPoly_t;
surfaceType_t* mySurfaceType = reinterpret_cast<surfaceType_t*>(mySrfPoly_t);
```

Comment: Note that here you're creating a *copy* of the data in `mySrfPoly_t.surfaceType`, while the OP is after a pointer to the original.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to cast from pointer to pointer. Thanks for the catch -- I've edited my answer to reflect this.